# Django view won't stop at breakpoint using Eclipse environment

Tags: django, eclipse, breakpoints

Looks like a stupid question, but I just can't make the code execution stop at breakpoint[image]

I tried to run the project by both pressing F9 and F11, but it still does not stop at the breakpoint. I use the local url http://127.0.0.1:8000/task_list/ which should call the createTask view. And it does actually call the view, and everything works perfect with the only exception that the debugger ignores all my breakpoints

Comment: Did you click the de`Bug` or the run arrow?

Comment: Run your project with the `Debug` option, usually `Mayus+F9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most major ide's have two different ways of running normally,

- Debug - This is usually denoted by some sort of bug image (as shown in your screenshot) or separate symbol
- Run - This is usually a "play" button

The debug mode is the one you want, this is the one that inserts debug symbols. The run doesn't set any of these up so you will find that your program may run slightly faster this way, which makes it more advantageous when modifying files that don't require you to restart the server.

Comment: Well, the project is in the Debug mode, and I pressed Debug As -> PyDev: Django

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan - Then the only other explanation I can think of is you have two versions of your `runserver` active.

Comment: Super. I pressed Terminate ALL (Ctrl + Alt + F9) and ran the app again and it stopped at the breakpoint. Thanks, @Sayse !!!